# What API endpoint to call to get a Kubernetes pod or service's yaml?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service

What api endpoint can I call to get a pod or service's yaml?

The kubectl command to get a pod's yaml is

> kubectl get pod my-pod -o yaml

but what endpoint does kubectl use to get it?

Comment: `kubectl get --raw https://kubernetes/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/my-pod |yq e -P -`, replace `kubectl get --raw` with `curl` and its flags as per authorization/authentication you have.

Answer (score 4):

> kubectl get pod my-pod -o yaml

> but what endpoint does kubectl use to get it?

If you add `-v 7` or `-v 6` to the command, you get verbose logs that show you all the **API requests**

Example:

```
kubectl get pods -v 6
I0816 22:59:03.047132   11794 loader.go:372] Config loaded from file:  /Users/jonas/.kube/config
I0816 22:59:03.060115   11794 round_trippers.go:454] GET https://127.0.0.1:52900/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods?limit=500 200 OK in 9 milliseconds
```

So you see that it does this API request:

```
/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods?limit=500
```

The API only returns the response in Json and the client can transform to Yaml when using `-o yaml`.